# Check if value doesn't exist in array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have to write a function that checks to see whether argument 1 (firstName) is a value in the array oj objects stored in variable (contacts) and if it is, return the current objects property value (prop). If firstName is not present, I have to return 'No contact found'. If a prop is not found, I have to return 'No such property'.

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to check whether the argument (firstName) is not found in the object of arrays. How does one write an if statement to check for that?

```js
var contacts = [
  {
    "firstName": "Akira",
    "lastName": "Laine",
    "number": "0543236543",
    "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Harry",
    "lastName": "Potter",
    "number": "0994372684",
    "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Sherlock",
    "lastName": "Holmes",
    'youtube': 'nah',
    "number": "0487345643",
    "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Kristian",
    "lastName": "Vos",
    "number": "unknown",
    "likes": ["Javascript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
  }
];

function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop){

  for (i=0;i<contacts.length;i++) {
    if (Object.values(contacts[i]).indexOf(firstName) > -1 && contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      return contacts[i][prop];
  }
    if (!contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      return 'No such property';
    }
  } 
}

lookUpProfile("Sherlock", "likes");
```

Comment: `contacts.find(obj => obj.firstName === firstName)[prop]`. Add intermediate truthy checking for `No contacts found` and `No property found`

Comment: I believe its convention to surround property keys in "quotes" in JSON, but I think its standard practice to leave your keys without them. i.e. instead of `"firstName": "Kristian"`, have `firstName: "Kristian"`.

Comment: @Li357 find has kinda anemic support, `(contacts.filter(obj => obj.firstName === firstName)[0] || {})[prop] || 'No such property';` works in all browsers including IE 9. Although admittedly less readable.

Comment: @JoelBiffin doesn't matter, question of taste

Comment: What shall the function return when there are two contacts with the wanted firstName, but only the second one has the wanted property?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use [`Array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to find the object with the correct `firstName`. You would use it as follows:

```
function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop) {
    var profile = contacts.find(function(contact) {
        return contact.firstName === firstName;
    });

    if (!profile) {
        console.log("no profile found for " + firstName);
        return;
    }

    if (!profile[prop]) {
        console.log("no " + prop + " found on " + firstName + " profile");
        return;
    }

    return profile[prop];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
var contacts = [{
    "firstName": "Akira",
    "lastName": "Laine",
    "number": "0543236543",
    "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Harry",
    "lastName": "Potter",
    "number": "0994372684",
    "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Sherlock",
    "lastName": "Holmes",
    'youtube': 'nah',
    "number": "0487345643",
    "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Kristian",
    "lastName": "Vos",
    "number": "unknown",
    "likes": ["Javascript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
  }
];

function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop) {

  var filter = contacts.filter(a => a.firstName === firstName);
  if (!filter.length) {
    return console.log('No contact found');
  }
  
  filter = filter.filter(a=> prop in a);
  
  if (!filter.length) {
    return console.log('No such property');
  }
  
  return filter;
}

lookUpProfile("Sherlock", "likes");
lookUpProfile("Sherlock", "hates");
lookUpProfile("Mycroft", "likes");
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var check = (first, prop) => (obj.map(cur => cur.firstName === first ? cur.firstName : "Not found")[0]);

var obj = [{
 firstName: "Eduardo",
 age: 17
}];

console.log(check(obj[0].firstName));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current approach doesn't allow to distinguish between the two error cases as your try to combine both conditions - name and property - in a single if condition within the loop body.

Also, your approach doesn't allow the user of the `lookUpProfile` function to distinguish between a real error and the special case when the prop exists and has the value `'No contact found'` or `'No such property'`. You might be better off throwing an exception instead of returning an error string.

A working approach is to first filter the candidates with matching name and then find the first candidate having the required property:

```
function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop) {
  const candidates = contacts.filter(contact => contact.firstName === firstName);
  if (candidates.length === 0) throw new Error('No contact found');
  const match = candidates.find(candidate => candidate.hasOwnProperty(prop));
  if (!match) throw new Error('No such property');
  return match[prop];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var contacts = [
  {
    "firstName": "Akira",
    "lastName": "Laine",
    "number": "0543236543",
    "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Harry",
    "lastName": "Potter",
    "number": "0994372684",
    "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Sherlock",
    "lastName": "Holmes",
    'youtube': 'nah',
    "number": "0487345643",
    "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Kristian",
    "lastName": "Vos",
    "number": "unknown",
    "likes": ["Javascript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
  }
];

function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop){

  for (i=0;i<contacts.length;i++) {
    if (Object.values(contacts[i]).indexOf(firstName) > -1 && contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      return contacts[i][prop];
  }
    if (!contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      return 'No such property';
    }
  } 
}

lookUpProfile("Sherlock", "likes");
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, here are some guidelines : *it is not recommended* to post code-only answers, answers should provide more explanation about the code to make it the answer more useful and are more likely to attract upvotes

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

**The first If determines:**

1.If name is in contacts AND if (prop) is a property.
2.If both conditions are true.
3.Then return that VALUE!.

**The else if determines:**

1.If name is in contacts AND (prop) is not a property. 
2.If both conditions are true. 
3.Then returns "No such property".

**The last return determines:** That for everything else, including a name not in the contacts, return "No such contact".

```js
// Setup
const contacts = [
  {
    firstName: "Akira",
    lastName: "Laine",
    number: "0543236543",
    likes: ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"],
  },
  {
    firstName: "Harry",
    lastName: "Potter",
    number: "0994372684",
    likes: ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"],
  },
  {
    firstName: "Sherlock",
    lastName: "Holmes",
    number: "0487345643",
    likes: ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"],
  },
  {
    firstName: "Kristian",
    lastName: "Vos",
    number: "unknown",
    likes: ["JavaScript", "Gaming", "Foxes"],
  },
];

function lookUpProfile(name, prop) {
  // Only change code below this line 
  for (let i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
    
      if ((name === contacts[i].firstName) &&   (contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop) === true)){
        console.log(contacts[i][prop]);
        return contacts[i][prop];
      }
      else if((name === contacts[i].firstName) &&(contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop) === false ) ){
        return "No such property";
      }
    }
  return "No such contact";
    
       
    }
 

  // Only change code above this line



lookUpProfile("Sherlock", "likes");
```